# Reduce instance of object/class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, singleton

I have a EditText field and I want to check validation input for this.
I applied MVVM + Databinding and invoke onTextChanged() method in ViewModel
Source :

xml

```
android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onMyTextChanged(text)}"
```

ViewModel.kt

```
fun onMyTextChanged(text) {
   // Show icon error if invalid, Show icon check done if valid
   val isValid = MyValidation(text).checkValid()
}
```

MyValidation.kt

```
class MyValidation(text: String){
  fun checkValid(): Boolean {  
    // Check text here with Regex Pattern
    <-- TODO  -->
    // Check instance time of class
    Log.d("INSTANCE", this.hashCode().toString() )
  }  
}
```

Console log:

```
INSTANCE : 159625389
INSTANCE : 178364275
INSTANCE : 190324272
...
```

Question:

When input text into EditText field , method onMyTextChanged will be called with the execution time = length of input Text.
Therefore, the instance of MyValidation class also increases. 
( See log )

I was thinking about using Object instead of Class to make Singleton by static. But I confuse that are there another solution for this case ?

Comment: Because you are creating new instance of that class each time the method is invoked. `MyValidation(text).checkValid()` is creating new instance each time for you.You have to create instance globally.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case you can use [Kotlin's extension Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/extension-functionsproperties.html) to check validity of text no need of a separate class to check validity. Extension function will be really convenient to use also.

Write the below code in same place as where u are checking the string validity but out side class body.

```
fun String.isValidString(): Boolean {
 // use this.length etc to refer to current string
 // Check text here with Regex Pattern
    <-- TODO  -->
    // log your String
    Log.d("Your String", this)
}
```

then your code will look like :

```
fun onMyTextChanged(text) {
   // Show icon error if invalid, Show icon check done if valid
   val isValid = text.isValidString()
}
```

Extra:
[**Reference**](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/extension-functions)

Comment: Sure if it works do upvote and accept the answer please